# HPのIPアドレスをドメインになおしたい

Tags: java, android

現状、あるデバイスとの通信アプリを作っているのですが、そのデバイスを通して
HPにアクセスするとHPのIPアドレスを送ってきます。

例えば、Yahooにアクセスした場合、「183.79.250.123」を返してくるので、
アプリ上ではこれをドメイン「yahoo.co.jp」に直して表示させたいです。

どうすればプログラム上でIPをドメインに直して表示できるかご教授願えませんでしょうか。

InetAddressクラスを使えばなんとかできると思ったのですがうまくいきませんでした。

```
URL url = new URL("http://183.79.250.123");
try {
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
   Host = address.toString();
}catch(UnknownHostException e){
}catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: ドメイン名 (っつか URL 内オーソリティ部) と IP アドレスは１対１対応しませんから、テキトーに変換しても希望通りにはいかない可能性が高いっす。

Comment: >>774RR様　　　デバイスは「サイトが現在使っているIP」を返してくるのですが、そのIPから「IPが使われている最新のドメイン名」を抽出するのが難しいということなのでしょうか?例えば、そのIPが過去に使われていたドメインがすべて表示されてしまうなどの弊害が考えられるということでしょうか。

Comment: デバイスにリクエストした段階でホスト名は分かっていると思うんだけど、レスポンスを元にホストを作り直さないといけない理由がわからない。やろうとしていることは逆引きなんだろうけど、少なくとも今現在はyahoo.co.jp引いても183.79.250.123出てこないですね。

Comment: ドメイン名を覚えておいて、返ってきたIPアドレスと紐付けてそのまま表示する…ではダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: >>ernix様、cubick様　　デバイスの開発者からドメインに直してほしいとの依頼を受けているの、でデバイスの方でドメイン名で送る仕様にできるはわかりません。できないか相談してみます。やりたいことは逆引きです。この言葉もernix様の投稿で初めて知ったので、これを検索ワードに追加して調べてみます。

Comment: デバイスというのがどんなものなのか、もう少し詳しい説明があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。(Androidもデバイスに含まれますよね？)

Comment: マイコンです。処理能力が低いため、マイコン内でネットにアクセスして得た情報をそのまま返す仕様なので、ドメインで帰ってきた情報ならそのままドメインでこちらに返してくれるのですがIPで帰ってきた情報はIPのままなのでアプリ内でドメインにしてほしいという内容だったはずです。非常に不確かな情報なので、担当者に問い合わせて正確なことが分かればこのコメントを消して書き換えます。今のところデバイス=マイコンであるというのだけが一番確かな情報です。

Comment: `getCanonicalHostName()` で逆引きをやるんですけど、すでに逆引けないんですよね。183.79.250.123。用途次第ですけど、この場合IPからホスト名を得るのはやめといた方がよさそうですよ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドメイン名と IP アドレスは1対1対応しませんので IP アドレスだけがあるとき、そこから元のドメイン名を取り戻すことはできません。ドメイン名っつか URL を覚えておく必要があります。

ドメイン名から IP アドレスを求めることを DNS の正引きとか順引きとか言います。
IP アドレスからドメイン名を求めることを DNS の逆引きといいます。
この両者は１対１対応ではないので正引き元と逆引き結果は必ずしも一致しません。
`Windows` では正引きを試すツールとして `nslookup` ってのがあります。

例：ドメイン名に複数の IP アドレスが振られている場合
`yahoo.co.jp` や `google.co.jp` などアクセス数が極めて多いドメインには複数の IP アドレスが降られています。アクセスがあるたび異なる IP アドレス＝異なるマシンに仕事を振ることで負荷分散しています。

```
C>nslookup google.co.jp
<中略> 以下同様
Address:   172.217.25.227
C>nslookup google.co.jp
Address:   172.217.26.35
C>
```

例：複数のドメイン名に同一の IP アドレスが振られている場合
`livedoor` ブログはたいてい `blog.livedoor.jp/<accountname>` でアクセスできます。
最近は `<accountname>.livedoor.blog` でもアクセスできるものがあるようです。
オイラの知り合いのブログもお引越しした際に、正式には後者の URL が振られましたが、わざと前者の形式でアクセスするとアクセスできて、後者のアドレスに正規化されてしまいます。

例として `blog.livedoor.jp/staff` と `staff.livedoor.blog` なら例に出して問題ないでしょう。

```
C>nslookup blog.livedoor.jp
Address:  203.104.130.159
C>nslookup staff.livedoor.blog
Address:  203.104.130.159
C>
```

というわけで逆引き結果は人間が期待しているものと異なってよくて、最初の結論となります。

Comment: >>sayuri様、池田茂樹様、774RR様　ありがとうございます。ドメインに直すのはデバイス開発者がマイコン内での処理を減らすためだそうです。ですが、IPとドメインが必ずしも遂にならない旨を説明し、IPのままの表記でも大丈夫という言質を取ることができました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: >>sayuri様　IPアドレスがいつのホスト名に対応するわけではない具体例をありがとうございます。  >>池田茂樹様　nslookupの情報をありがとうございます。今回は使う機会がありませんでしたがまた参照させていただきます。  >>774RR様　逆引きがむ難しい原理の解説をありがとうございます。774RRのコメントを使ってデバイスの開発者を説得できたため、ベストアンサーとさせていただきます。  その他コメントをくださった皆様も含めまして本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

ここStack Overflowを例にとっても

```
Name:    ja.stackoverflow.com
Addresses:  151.101.129.69
          151.101.1.69
          151.101.65.69
          151.101.193.69

Name:    stackoverflow.com
Addresses:  151.101.65.69
          151.101.129.69
          151.101.193.69
          151.101.1.69
```

となっていて、

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com （日本語版）
- https://stackoverflow.com （英語版）

どちらも同じIPアドレスを使用しています。当然、IPアドレスからホスト名に戻すことは不可能です。

Answer (score 1):

参考になるかわかりませんが、nslookupをやっているソフトのURLを張っておきます。
https://github.com/hsccorp/cordova-dnsjava-nslookup/blob/master/src/android/Nslookup.java